# SQL Trigger - Check into other Table, If exists then Update else Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

MSSQL

I have two tables. TableA and TableB

**TableA**

```
+----+----+-----+
| ID |Name|Marks|
+----+----+-----+
| 1  |ABC |50   |
+----+----+-----+
| 2  |BCD |80   |
+----+----+-----+
```

**TableB**

```
+----+----+-----+
| ID |Name|Marks|
+----+----+-----+
| 1  |ABC |50   |
+----+----+-----+
| 4  |PQR |10   |
+----+----+-----+
```

On every insert into TableA I want to check if the same ID is there in TableB or not.
If ID is not there in TableB then insert record into TableB,  if ID found in TableB then update record in TableB.

How can i write trigger on TableA for these inserts.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and show the code that you have attempted.  This doesn't seem particularly tricky if you can write a trigger and `update` statement.

Comment: Valid ANSI/ISO standard SQL would be using a updatable view with check option

Answer (score 3):

This type of logic is a little tricky in SQL Server because it handles inserts as *sets* rather than as individual rows.

So, you might as well try the `update` and `insert` on all the values, using logic like this:

```
create trigger on tablea after insert
begin
    -- update everything that matches
    update b
        set marks = a.marks
        from tableb b join
             inserted a
             on b.id = a.id;

    -- insert what doesn't match
    insert into tableb
        select a.id, a.name, a.marks
        from inserted a
        where not exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.id = a.id);
end;
```